# Python equivalent of `io.Copy`

Tags: python, sockets, go, proxy

I'm trying to implement a tcp proxy with python,

So I need to connect two sockets directly, passing input and output in between.

In golang, I simply do a `io.Copy`, what's the equivalent in Python 2.6?

```
go func() {
    defer conn1.Close()
    defer conn2.Close()
    io.Copy(conn1, conn2)
}()
```

Comment: `shutil.copyfileobj` with `socket.socket.makefile`.

Comment: @NizamMohamed can you provide an example?

Comment: @NizamMohamed does not work for me, `shutil.copyfileobj(sock1.makefile(), sock2.makefile())`

Comment: clarify what a "tcp proxy" is and where it fits in. In TCP one end initiates a connection (client) and another end receives (server). which end you're talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use function like this:

```
def CopyProxy(conn1, conn2):    
    while True:        
        data = conn2.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)        
        try:            
            conn1.send(data)            
            if not data:                
              conn1.close()              
              conn2.close()                
              break        
        except Exception:            
              break
```

Then launch them in separate threads:

```
# conn1 and conn2 - previously opened connections "to" and "from"
t1 = threading.Thread(target=CopyProxy, args=[conn1, conn2])
t2 = threading.Thread(target=CopyProxy, args=[conn2, conn1])   
t1.start() 
t2.start()
```